# ps command not found in CentOS

Tags: ps, subversion

Today morning I was trying to start Collabnet svn with the `/home/svn/csvn/bin/csvn start` command.

However, I got error like below:

```
[root@dev bin]# ./csvn start 
Unable to locate 'ps'.
Please report this message along with the location of the command on your system.
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If the ps command is missing you can reinstall it using

```
yum install -y procps
```